# Convert.ToDouble() overflows with SqlDataReader value

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

```
Convert.ToDouble(rdr["value"])
```

Throws a "Conversion overflows" error when value is 75875563.7000000000000000000000 as displayed in SQL Server.

[image]

Stack Trace:

```
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Decimal()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Value()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValueFromSqlBufferInternal(SqlBuffer data, _SqlMetaData metaData)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValueInternal(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name)
   at DataAPI.Models.Title.TitleDB.getTitlePerformance(Nullable`1 StartDate, Nullable`1 EndDate) in c:\00 BI Source\BIPortal\DataAPI\DataAPI\Models\Title\TitleDB.cs:line 44
```

Can someone give me a clue on why this is?

Comment: Should it be converted to decimal, and then cast to double?

Comment: @pavlindrom - It works when I cast as decimal(11,2) in the query. One of the columns in the calculation of that value was a decimal(17,2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about decimal capacity. Can you use decimal (16,4) on sql server side (or some precision you need)? decimal (16,4) means 16 chars, 4 digits after ,

Comment: Thanks, I guess 17,2 was too much for C#